# Same input works different on different code

Tags: python, input, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, gpio

I have 2 different codes for the same input. The most basic one(knoptest.py(translate to buttontest.py)) works as intented. When i press the button the terminal writes "aan"(translate to "on") until i let go. However, in my more difficult code(discodouch.py(translate to discoshower)) the terminal writes "uit"(off) for a couple of times, somewhere between 1 and 20 times aprox. After then it "aan"(on) once and stays there, even without me pressing the button.

I've tried fixing it on the hardware side without any result. I've also tried copying the lines from the test file to the real file to check for spelling/other writing errors

knoptest.py:

```py
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(38, GPIO.IN)

while True:
    if GPIO.input(38) == 1:
        print('aan')
```

discodouch.py:

```py
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(38, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)

tijd = 0
GPIO.output(16, 0)

while True:
    GPIO.output(16, 0)
    tijd = 0
    print('uit')
    if GPIO.input(38) == 1:
        GPIO.output(16, 1)
        print('aan')
        while tijd <= 2:
            time.sleep(60)
            tijd = tijd + 1
            print('1 minuuten voorbij')
```

No error messages when compiling or running. However the code is supposed to jump to the "on state" when i press the button. Not after somewhere between 1 and 20 cycles at random.

Comment: You're putting your python script to sleep for two minutes after the button is pressed - if that's not what you expect to happen, why is the `sleep()` part present?

Comment: Yes @matslindh, that is what is supposed to happen. But he isnt supposed to be "on" when i am not pressing

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

I can't run your code on my laptop (requires a RasPi), but it sounds like you are experiencing a phenomenon called button-bouncing. Currently, your code does not handle this problem.

## End TL;DR

Essentially, the button you are expecting is an ideal button. An ideal button only presses once when you push down on the button. A realistic button (the one you have) "bounces" up and down before tapering off in the depressed position. There are more discussions about this topic on the Arduino [stack exchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-to-simulate-delay-to-debounce-mechanical-button-using-millis) that elaborate on this subject in much more detail.

Basically, you need to de-bounce the button so that it reads like an ideal button. You need to either use an IC (Integrated Circuit) that specifically solves this problem, some software logic, or a simple (tiny) capacitor** in series of the signal input to properly read the value of the button.

There are many different ways of solving this problem, and I haven't paid too much attention to your code, but I know, with %100 certainty, that you need to take care of button debouncing before you can reliably write programs that use buttons, and I don't see that in your code. I should mention that debouncing only matters if you care about sensitivity and timing, but I don't know the application requirements to recommend you otherwise.

Basically, without knowing the hardware configuration, that is the best I (or anybody) can give you.

** A capacitor would automatically add a delay, but it would prevent a bunch of readings of both high and low before choosing a polarity. I suggest you hook up an oscilloscope and see for yourself how the output of the button reacts.

Comment: I'll look into it. However, why is my button bouncing in one script, but not in the other?

Comment: Well, according to the filenames, you say the first script is using a knob, while the second script is using a push-button. I don't know if that is different naming or different hardware. If you are using something like a double pole single switch knob for the first script, those behave differently. I would need to know more about your hardware setup to give you more info.

Comment: I would also recommend using pull-up or pull-down resistors to force your signal one way or the other, than have the button negate that signal. Basically, you need to do more signal filtering before saying your code is right or wrong. Also, we can't debug your input signal, so we can only make guesses there.